# Restrictions of private tow companies in Arizona regarding holding the vehicle for payment

Tags: vehicle, arizona, motor-vehicle

I live in Arizona, and around 5 years ago, my car was towed out of my parking spot in my apartment complex, because I forgot to put the registration sticker on the plate. I was able to research it on the internet and found out that unless the tow was ordered by a police officer, the private tow yard couldn't hold my property for payment, or demand any billing information to bill me later. All I had to show them was the cars registration and a valid ID with a name matching whats on the cars registration. The lady at the front desk gave me a hard time saying that wasn't true, but when her manager came over, I shoed him the statute I had printed out, and he instructed her to release my car without billing me. They eventually had to go after the apartment complex, since thats who they had the contract with, and the complex couldn't give them my billing information (or any other personal information). Eventually they just dropped it all together (and asked me very nicely to put my sticker on the plate.. lol)

A friend of mine is in a nearly identical situation, private tow company, he's the vehicle owner, the tow was **not** ordered by police, etc etc. I wanted to help him out and tell him what statute number to look up, but I can't seem to find it... I see all kinds of articles explaining this exact scenario, and the majority of them conclude with "they can hold it for money if it was towed by the cops. Otherwise, no", but no ARS #'s are referenced. And any ARS # that ***are*** referenced are more about impounding or DUI's, which isn't what this is about.

If this has been changed recently, then when? If not, where is it referenced? I searched for **towing** at **www.AZLeg.gov**, and there are quite a few [results](http://www.azleg.gov/searchresultsDOC/?insearch=towing&titles=0), but I haven't been able to find what I had before, and I remember it was a pain to find last time as well.

If anyone can provide some insight in regards to the rights of the tow company and the vehicle owner, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you!